# Structuring models with ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've started using ember data and I'm having some issues getting started. If my json structure for ingredients is:

```
[
   {
      "name":"flax seed",
      "retailer":"www.retailer.com",
      "nutrient_info":[
         {
            "type":"vitamin A",
            "amount":"50mg"
         },
         {
            "type":"calcium",
            "amount":"30mg"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"soy milk",
      "retailer":"www.retailer-two.com",
      "nutrient_info":[
         {
            "type":"vitamin D",
            "amount":"500mg"
         },
         {
            "type":"niacin",
            "amount":"5000mg"
         }
      ]
   },
   { other ingredients... }
]
```

I think this is how I would define my models:

```
var attr = DS.attr,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany,
    belongsTo = DS.belongsTo

App.Ingredients = DS.Model.extend({
    // id: attr('number'),  // don't include id in model?
    name: attr('string'),
    retailer: attr('string'),
    nutrientinfo: hasMany('nutrients')
})

App.Nutrients = DS.Model.extend({
    type: attr('string'),
    amount: attr('string'),

    ingredient: belongsTo('ingredients')
})
```

What should the server payload look like, and would I need to customize the REST adapter? Do I need to define the ingredient `id: attr()` in the model?

Any help in clarifying some of these concepts is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally model definitions are singular (additionally I changed nutrientinfo to nutrient_info):

```
App.Ingredient = DS.Model.extend({
    // id: attr('number'),  // don't include id in model?
    name: attr('string'),
    retailer: attr('string'),
    nutrient_info: hasMany('nutrient')
})

App.Nutrient = DS.Model.extend({
    type: attr('string'),
    amount: attr('string'),
    ingredient: belongsTo('ingredient')
})
```

The format would need to be as follows (from the endpoint, or using a serializer)

```
{
  // Ingredient records
  ingredients:[
    {
      id:1,
      "name":"flax seed",
      "retailer":"www.retailer.com",
      "nutrient_info":[1,2]
    },
    {
      id:2,
      "name":"soy milk",
      "retailer":"www.retailer-two.com",
      "nutrient_info":[3,4]
    },
    { other ingredients... }
  ],

  // Nutrient records
  nutrients: [
    {
      id:1,
      "type":"vitamin A",
      "amount":"50mg",
      ingredient:1
    },
    {
       id:2,
       "type":"calcium",
       "amount":"30mg",
      ingredient:1
    },
    {
       id:3,
       "type":"vitamin D",
       "amount":"500mg",
      ingredient:2
    },
    {
       id:4,
       "type":"niacin",
       "amount":"5000mg",
      ingredient:2
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's an example using a serializer and your json, I've had to manually assign ids (despite this being invalid, you should send down ids, or use UUIDs), but this should give you an idea of how to use the serializer:

```
App.IngredientSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType)   {
    var ingredients = payload,
        nutrientId = 0,
        ingredientId = 0,
        ids = [],
        nutrients = [];

    ingredients.forEach(function(ing) {
      ing.id = ingredientId++;
      var nInfo = ing.nutrient_info,
          nIds = [];

      nInfo.forEach(function(n){
        n.id = nutrientId++;
        n.ingredient = ing.id;
        nIds.push(n.id);
        nutrients.push(n);
      });
      ing.nutrient_info = nIds;
    });

    payload = {ingredients:ingredients, nutrients:nutrients};

    return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/537/edit

Comment: So just to clarify, the JSON requested from the server doesn't need to be split into `ingredients` and `nutrients` separately because the serializer does that, right?

Comment: it does, the serializer doesn't do that by default.

Comment: Here's some good documentation until it comes out of beta: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: To follow up: I removed the `ing.id = ingredientId++;` part and added a unique ID to each ingredient so it's passed down from the JSON. Would it be beneficial to do the same thing with nutrients, and give each one a unique id?